# Why is the Bluetooth security key for FIDO gone?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, titan, fido

I know that in 2019, the Bluetooth security key failed and all Titan Google keys were recovered.
Since then, can't fido use Bluetooth keys?
I'm trying to connect BLE with a webAuthn client using the 3rd party app, and I don't see any examples of it.

I wonder if it's an impossible attempt.

So far, what we've tried is that you can connect with a webAuthn client by manually pairing Android apps with pc.
But I want to do registration and authentication without pairing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you sure that [tag:titan] is the right tag for your question? looks like it is for a database. You can [edit] your question to add or remove tags

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Both WebAuthn and CTAP specifications support BLE, however not all of implementations of WebAuthn support BLE. 
For what it seems you are asking how to do FIDO with a non paired BLE hardware key, which isn't possible as that would breach the CTAP2 or U2F specification. Neither of them allows for using BLE with a LTK present. 

But as said, question is very unclear and unsure if this is actually what you are asking.